# Upload / add file from off-repo local directory to git repo

Tags: git, github

I am still clueless how to add a simple image file on my desktop to a repo on my github account.

I have a simple JPEF file at /home/users/pierre/my-photo.jpg

I would like to upload this photo to repo called `webpage`, which is associated with `gh-pages` branch.

1) Is there a way that I can do this via web interface? (or some simple drag-and-drop approach)

2) How can I do this on terminal?

What I did so far:

```
git clone https://github.com/username/username.github.io 

cd username.github.io

git checkout gh-pages # added this to solve the problem

mv Desktop/photo.jpg ./

git add photo.jpg

git status     

git comment -m "photo added"

git push
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should `add` the file to the repo before committing:

```
mv Desktop/photo.jpg ./
git add photo.jpg     
git commit -m "photo added"
```

---

Edit:

`git status` should let you understand what's going on.

Before the `mv` you should have:

```
> git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

After you should have:

```
> mv Desktop/photo.jpg ./
> git status
# On branch master
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   photo.jpg
nothing added to commit but untracked files present (use "git add" to track)
```

It means that Git sees that there's a new file, but as far as commits are concerned, it doesn't take it into account.
It means that if you need to `add` photo.jpg to the repo. Otherwise, if you try to commit now, you'll get the error `nothing to commit`.

If you look at the status after adding the file, you'll get:

```
> git add photo.jpg
> git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   photo.jpg
#
```

Now, Git is telling us that there are `Changes to be committed`. So now, `git commit` will work fine

Comment: Thank you for the reply! When I commit, I get this error message: # On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean

Comment: Solved - turns out that I need to switch to the correct branch first. I just assumed for some reason that changes to master apply to 'linked' branches as well. In any case, git checkout gh-pages did the trick. Thank you.

Comment: I posted my edit while you were writing your 2nd comment. Feel free to ignore it then. Glad to know you succeeded.